# Getting "Exception has occurred: TypeError '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable" when looping through CSV with selenium and panda, python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, pandas

Hey I am currently trying to use data from a csv with my selenium script.
Currently using

```
    f = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
    f.head()
    for index in range(len(f.index)):
        Bestellnummer = f["Bestellnummer"][index]
        Sendungsnummer = f["Sendungsnummer"][index]
```

First row works fine but after that I am getting the error:

```
"Exception has occurred: TypeError '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable"
```

on the second row...anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Question needs improvement

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to instead iterate over the rows using [`.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html?highlight=iterrows#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows). For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    Bestellnummer = row["Bestellnummer"]
    Sendungsnummer = row["Sendungsnummer"]
    
    print(Bestellnummer, Sendungsnummer)
```

See also: [`.itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas-dataframe-itertuples)